# Can't return current keyboard language

Tags: android

in app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 78
        versionName "3.36"
```

I want to detect current keyboard's language when click button for change language on soft keyboard:

[image]

in fragment I try to get current keyboard's language like this:

```
  @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                    if (editable.length() == 1) {
                        System.out.println("Locale.getDefault().getLanguage()  = " + RTLUtils.getCurrentInputLanguageLocale(getActivity()));
                    }
                }


 public static String getCurrentInputLanguageLocale(Context context) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
        String locale = ims.getLocale();
        return locale;
    }
```

but always return empty locale